# get value from startup window

Tags: c#, wpf

I changed the startup window at the `app.xaml` with this code:

```
Startup="ApplicationStart"
```

At the `app.xaml.cs` file is this method:

```
    private void ApplicationStart(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

        ChooseAccountWindow chooseAccountWindow = new ChooseAccountWindow();
        chooseAccountWindow.ShowDialog();
    }
```

The Code of the window (`ChooseAccountWindow()`):

```
public partial class ChooseAccountWindow : MetroWindow
{
    public ChooseAccountWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnDastaschentuch2013_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //send value "dastaschentuch2013" to the main window
    }

    private void btnSkeptar_de_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //send value "skeptar_de" to the main window
    }

    private void btnAsdf_de_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //send value "asdf_de" to the main window
    }
}
```

If I press one of the button`s, then a value should be send to the main code. How can I do that?

---

**Answer**

I had to change the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` code:

```
namespace EbayManager
{
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    private string selectedAccount;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public MainWindow(string selectedAccount): this()
    {
        this.selectedAccount = selectedAccount;


    }
}
}
```

Comment: Should ChooseAccountWindow window be closed when you click buttons in it?

Comment: So, ChooseAccountWindow should disappear, and **after** that MainWindow should appear with result that depends on which button was clicked, is it correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public partial class ChooseAccountWindow : MetroWindow
{
    public string Result { get; set; }

    public ChooseAccountWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnDastaschentuch2013_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Result = "dastaschentuch2013";
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnSkeptar_de_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Result = "skeptar_de";
        this.Close();
    }

    private void btnTrachsel_de_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Result = "trachsel_de";
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

In App.xaml remove StartupUri to prevent automatical main window opening

In App.xaml.cs:

```
private void ApplicationStart(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

    ChooseAccountWindow chooseAccountWindow = new ChooseAccountWindow();
    chooseAccountWindow.ShowDialog();

    MainWindow main = new MainWindow(chooseAccountWindow.Result);
    // insert your startup uri class name instead of MainWindow;
    // add constructor to this window that will take string as input parameter
    main.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! :) But at the last command `Run()`, I get an `InvalidOperationException`. When I delete this command it works fine!

Comment: Hm... I dont know. I get my custom window first, then I press one button and the `mainWindow` will open, but I cant change anything (title, width, height, ...) on the `MainWindow.xaml`. My custom window should only be a window where I can choose the account = not the main window. But I think at the moment its the main window, and the real main window (`MainWindow.xml`) is only a secondary window.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Yes, Run() was a mistake. I will remove it from my answer. What's about you cannot change title, width and height - I'm not able to reproduce it. I've checked that Application.Current.MainWindow is of MainWindow type after MainWindow is loaded. If you can provide more information or share sample issued project - I would try to help you

Comment: I had to change the `MainWindow.xaml.cs` code. The programm didn't execute the method(?) `InitializeComponent();`. I will post the code in my question. But I have one big problem. If I close the second window (MainWindow.xaml) with the cross in the edge at the top, the debugger wont stop. (I think the applcation wont stop running) I dont know how to fix it. Maybe you have an idea.

Comment: In ApplicationStart you wrote Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown; That means you have call Application.Current.Shutdown(). Only after that application will be stopped (and debugger too). If you want to shutdown application when MainWindow is closed, add Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClosed; to the end of ApplicationStart (and **do not ** remove Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;)

Comment: Hmmm..... Thanks for the anwer! :) It works perfect. The next half hour I will try to understand it :P

Again, thanks for your help yesterday & today.

Answer (score 1):

If I read you correctly, you can reference the main window like this:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow and then set a property on it.


void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Current.MainWindow.MyProperty = "SomeValue";
    MainWindow.ShowDialog();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Must I write this in the `app.xaml.cs` file or in the other window code?